# $r+r^{-1}$ integral implies $r^n+r^{-n}$ integral

Tags: induction

Suppose r + 1/r is an integer. r is real and positve. How to prove r^n + 1/r^n is an integer by induction for all natural numbers n.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $(r+\frac{1}{r})^n$ which you know is an integer. If you expand this out and group together terms of the form $r^i + \frac{1}{r^i}$ you see that
$$(r+\frac{1}{r})^n = \sum_{i=0}^{\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor } \binom{n}{i} \left(r^{n-2i} + \frac{1}{r^{n-2i}} \right)$$

You know that the left hand side is an integer and by induction you have that all of the terms on the right hand side except for the leading term $r^{n} + \frac{1}{r^{n}}$ are integers. Hence $r^{n} + \frac{1}{r^{n}}$ must be an integer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. By hypothesis if $n=1$ then the relation holds. Suposse that for every $m$ such that $m\leq n$ the relation holds. Therefore consider the product
$$(x+x^{-1})(x^n+x^{-n}) $$
and deduce the result from the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Nice approach, simple: on expansion = $(x^{n+1} + x^{-(n+1)}) + (x^{n-1} + x^{-(n-1)})$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply mathematical induction using the identity:
$$x^{n+2}+x^{-n-2} = (x+x^{-1})(x^{n+1}+x^{-n-1})-(x^{n}+x^{-n})$$