# Proof question that could be proved using mathematical induction.

Tags: induction

$T_1=x+1/x$ is an integer greater than $2$. Prove that $x^n+x^{-n}$ is an integer. For what values on $n$, $t_1$ divides $t_n$.

I am stuck with this problem. Please help.

Comment: You can find a few posts related to the first part of the problem [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5En%2Bx%5E%7B-n%7D%24&p=1). For example: [$r+r^{-1}$ integral implies $r^n+r^{-n}$ integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/768072) or [$S_n$ is an integer for all integers $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1827466). More tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936479/proving-that-frac-phi4001-phi200-is-an-integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x^{n+1}+\frac 1 {x^{n+1}})=(x^{n}+\frac 1 {x^{n}}) (x+\frac 1 x)-(x^{n-1}+\frac 1 {x^{n-1}})$. Hence $T_{n+1}=T_nT_1-T_{n-1}$. Thus $T_1$ divides $T_{n-1}$ iff it divides $T_{n+1}$.  Can you answer the second part using this?

Comment: oh thank you so much.i'd grateful if you consider answering the second part too,i am not sure about it